# PHP / MySQL. Could not update data: Query was empty

Tags: php, mysql, sql

First of all I like to say that I'm super bad at this type of stuff so my code can be totally useless.

The mission is to create a system that will ask the user to scan two ID's, userID and itemID. After the scan has been successful I want these values to be transported to a PHP document. 
Here I'd like to run a MySQL query which will update the value of userID where itemID match the database.

So my problem is that I get this message after running my query: 
userID:202 itemID:8204 Could not update data: Query was empty. And ofc my database remains empty.

I think the problem is that the query can't read the $_GET variables. But I have no clue so please help me, Thanks!

This is my form:

```
<form id="checkin" name="checkin" action="test.php">
<input type="button" onclick="checkIn()" value="Check in Item">
</form>
```

The function:

```
<script>
function checkIn(){ 
var userID=parseInt(prompt ("Scan userid"), 10);
var itemID=parseInt(prompt ("Scan itemid"), 10);
if(userID!=null && itemID!=null){ 
window.location.href= "http://localhost/webapp/test.php?userID=" + userID + "&itemID=" + itemID; 
alert ("working so far userID:"+ userID + " --- itemID:" + itemID);             
 }
}
</script>
```

At last the PHP:

```
$con = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "", "book1");
$db  = mysql_select_db('book1');

if (isset($_GET["userID"]) && isset($_GET["itemID"])) {
    $userID1 = (int)$_GET["userID"];
    $itemID2 = (int)$_GET["itemID"];
    $test    = "userID: ".$_GET["userID"]." "."itemID: ".$_GET["itemID"];
    echo $test;
}
if (!$con) {
    die('Could not connect: '.mysql_error());
}
$upd = mysql_query('UPDATE INTO booking SET userID ="$userID" WHERE ID ="$itemID');

$retval = mysql_query($upd, $con);
if (!$retval) {
    die('Could not update data: '.mysql_error());
}
echo "Updated data successfully\n";
```

Comment: `UPDATE INTO booking` should be `UPDATE booking`

Comment: Not directly related to your question but you may want to consider using PDO. Casting to `int` seems like a very ugly way to sanitize input for SQL.

Comment: Yeah I already have consider using PDO and I think I will in the near future. I just like to get this function to work first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Invalid arguments @ `mysql_connect()`

```
$con=mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die ('Connection failed' . mysql_error());

$db = mysql_select_db('book1',$con);
```

`UPDATE INTO` need to change to `UPDATE ....`

Also you have `userID` assigned to variable `$userID1` and `itemID` assigned to `$itemID2`. But in your query it is wrong. Query is updated now.

[Mysql Manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html)

Also missing quotes at `WHERE ID ="$itemID'`

```
$upd = mysql_query("UPDATE booking SET userID ='$userID1' WHERE ID ='$itemID2'", $con);
```

P.S. Usage of mysql_* functions is not advised, instead use mysqli_*

Comment: Fixed all of the problems and now I get a syntax error saying: You have a error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server verison for the right syntaxto use near '1' at line 1. Please help me! Thanks!

Comment: @user3751216 there was a problem in ur variables. I have updated the code. Please try now.

Answer (score 0):

Your DB connection string might looks `mysqli_`. In `mysql_`, you don't want to specify the `DB Name` as parameter.

```
$con=mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "", "book1");
```

This should be,

```
$con=mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
```

You add unnecessary `INTO` in `UPDATE` query..

[Refer the manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html)
Try this,

```
UPDATE booking SET ....
```

instead of,

```
UPDATE INTO booking SET ....
```

You might also want to read this: [Why shouldn't I use mysql_* functions in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php)

Answer (score 0):

Correct your connection as per manual and also correct `Update` syntax

Check [PHP CONNECTION](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mysql_connect.asp) Manual

```
$con=mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") OR die('Could not connect');
$db = mysql_select_db('book1',$con);
if(isset($_GET["userID"]) && isset($_GET["itemID"])){
$userID1= (int) $_GET["userID"];
$itemID2= (int) $_GET["itemID"];
$test = "userID: ". $_GET["userID"] . " " . "itemID: ". $_GET["itemID"];
echo $test;
}
$upd = mysql_query("UPDATE booking SET userID='".$userID."' WHERE ID=$itemID");

$retval = mysql_query( $upd);
if(! $retval){
    die('Could not update data: ' . mysql_error());
}
echo "Updated data successfully\n";
}
```

Comment: Fixed all of the problems and now I get a syntax error saying: You have a error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server verison for the right syntax to use near '1' at line 1. Please help me! Thanks!

Comment: If your problem is not solved then how can you accept answer?

Comment: Well i'm new to this so I clicked on accept answer before I checked for upcoming errors.

Comment: I putted it in an answer for this question, give me a moment

Answer (score 0):

@user3751216 the error of the "syntax" problem it's generated on this line

```
$upd = mysql_query("UPDATE booking SET userID='".$userID."' WHERE ID=$itemID");

$retval = mysql_query( $upd);
```

If you put your code like this, it should resolve the problem of the SQL syntax

```
$upd = ("UPDATE booking SET userID='".$userID."' WHERE ID=$itemID");

$retval = mysql_query( $upd);
```

Let me now if you already resolve the problem.